# Extending Visual Studio 2010 'Professional' edition with additional features available in 'Premium' edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, open-source

If not *programming*, this certainly is a *programmer's* question.

Visual Studio 2010 **Express** and **Ultimate** editions are two extremes wherein the former is for *hobbyists* and the latter is (primarily) for *Architects/Designers*.

The price gap between **Professional** and **Premium** editions is HUGE; however, both target developers (testers and DB guys too) primarily.

In case I wish to extend my **Professional** edition with most of the features provided with **Premium** edition additionally, I look up to the **Open Source** world and/or other commercial alternatives.

Therefore I request people to suggest good quality alternatives to the additional features in the **Premium** edition. I am hereby enlisting the additional features available with the **Premium** edition w.r.t. features available in the **Professional** edition:

**Debugging and Diagnostics**
 - Static Code Analysis
 - Code Metrics
 - Profiling

**Testing Tools**
 - Code Coverage
 - Test Impact Analysis
 - Coded UI Test

**Database Development**
 - Database Deployment
 - Database Change Management
 - Database Unit Testing
 - Database Test Data Generation

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives.

### Static Code Analysis

I think both [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) have some features that fit in this category.

### Profiling

- [Red Gate ANTS performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)
- [Red Gate ANTS memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

### Code coverage

- [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/)
- [JetBrains dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/)